# Convert Python list into dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have list like this :

```
mylist = [
    {"name":"fname1","value":"ardian"},
    {"name":"frm2","value":"febri"},
    {"name":"frm3","value":"jalan ciwaruga"}
]
```

and I want this list coverted into a dictionary like this:

```
mydict = {
    {"name":"fname1","value":"ardian"},
    {"name":"frm2","value":"febri"},
    {"name":"frm3","value":"jalan ciwaruga"}
}
```

Is there any solution to do this?

Comment: That's a set of dictionaries.

Comment: that's not a dictionary. a dictionarty has keys, otherwise it does not make sense. what are your keys?

Comment: Thank you Bill, for your correction, since I new in python, my keys are: firstname, lastname and address.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you tell us exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you are looking to convert name's value as key and value's value as value , you can do it. Example: mydict = { 'fname1': 'ardian', 'fname2': febri', 'frm3': 'jalan ciwaruga' } by doing this { x.keys()[0]: x[x.keys()[0]] for x in mylist }

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what you want to do.

Do this:

```
mydict = {}

for dic in mylist:
    mydict.update( { dic['name']:dic['value'] } )
```

To convert your list into this:

```
mydict = {
    'fname1':'ardian',
    'frm2':'febri',
    'frm3':'jalan ciwaruga'
}
```

If you want to use the index of the list to convert into keys, do this:

```
mydict = {}

for i in range(len(mylist)):
    mydict.update({ i:mylist[i] })
```

To convert your list into this:

```
mydict = {
    0:{"name":"fname1","value":"ardian"},
    1:{"name":"frm2","value":"febri"},
    2:{"name":"frm3","value":"jalan ciwaruga"}
}
```

Hope this helps! If I'm solving the wrong problem, can you please explain more what you need solving?

**Edit:**
To access each kind of dictionary, do this:

```
#For the first dictionary
mydict['fname1'] # --> 'ardian'
mydict['frm2'] # --> 'febri'
mydict['frm3'] # --> 'jalan ciwargua'

#For the second dictionary
mydict[0] # --> {'name':'fname1', 'value':'ardian'}
mydict[1] # --> {'name':'frm2', 'value':'febri'}
mydict[2] # --> {'name':'frm3', 'value':'jalan ciwargua'}
```

However, the second dictionary acts just like a list, so I don't know why you would want it. It would be quite redundant, unless you need something specific for that purpose...

Comment: that exactly what i mean, the second one. But how if I want the keys is not integer but string?

Comment: Can you rephrase that? I don't understand what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
mylist = [
    {"name":"fname1","value":"ardian"},
    {"name":"frm2","value":"febri"},
    {"name":"frm3","value":"jalan ciwaruga"}
]

mydict = dict(enumerate(mylist))
```

which gives:

```
{
    0: {'name': 'fname1', 'value': 'ardian'},
    1: {'name': 'frm2', 'value': 'febri'},
    2: {'name': 'frm3', 'value': 'jalan ciwaruga'}
}
```

or if you want string keys do:

```
mydict = dict((str(i), d) for i,d in enumerate(mylist))
```

which gives:

```
{
    '0': {'name': 'fname1', 'value': 'ardian'},
    '1': {'name': 'frm2', 'value': 'febri'},
    '2': {'name': 'frm3', 'value': 'jalan ciwaruga'}
}
```

The docs for `enumerate`[1] and `dict`[2] can help explain what is going on!

[1] https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

[2] https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict